# Rails 4 - Coffee script form helper & cross browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, forms, coffeescript

Im using rails 4 to make a web app.

I have a form in my projects view folder, which has nested questions. If the answer to a top level question is true, then further sub questions will be displayed. If the answer is false, then the sub questions related to that top level question remain hidden.

I have a form helper in my javascripts folder which has the hide/show functions for that form. It works fine when I use Chrome as my browser. It doesn't work at  all in safari. In safari, all form elements, including those that are supposed to be hidden at the start, are displayed.

How do I adjust the form helper so that it works on all browsers?

In my JS form helper file I have:

```
# source input attrs: {class: 'toggle_div', target: <TARGET_ID_OR_CLASS>}
# toggle_radio attr : {class: 'toggle_div', target: <TARGET_ID_OR_CLASS>, toggle_reverse: <anything> }
#$ ->
#  $(document).on 'change', 'input.toggle_div', ()->
#    $($(this).attr('target')).toggle this.checked
#
#  $(document).on 'change', 'input.toggle_radio', ()->
#    reverse = $(this).attr('toggle_reverse')
#    if reverse
#      toggle_value = ($(this).val() == 'false')
#    else
#      toggle_value = ($(this).val() == 'true')
#    target = $(this).attr('target')
#    $(target).toggle toggle_value



#$ ->




$ ->
  setTheAttributes = (inString)->

    if $('#' + inString +  '_sweep_attributes_if_datum').is(':checked')
      $('#datarequest').show()
    else
      $('#datarequest').hide()
    $(document).on 'change', '#' + inString +  '_sweep_attributes_if_datum', ()->
      if $('#' + inString + '_sweep_attributes_if_datum').is(':checked')
        $('#datarequest').show()
      else
        $('#datarequest').hide()


 formList = document.getElementsByTagName "form"

  if(formList[0].action.includes "/projects")
    setTheAttributes 'project'
  if(formList[0].action.includes "/programs")
    setTheAttributes 'program'
  if(formList[0].action.includes "/proposals")
    setTheAttributes 'proposal'
```

In my application.js file I have:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-switch
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean? The way I have it works fine in Chrome.

Comment: i belive that line 17 need more 1 space, and you should add more  code to debug (`console.log`) such as: getting formList is correct, setTheAttributes has been called,  event `changed` is triggered,...

Comment: Which line do you think is 17? for me, that line has nothing on it. I also don't know what you mean about adding code to console.log. Do you think it works in Chrome but doesn't in safari because of spaces?